# angularjs directives error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create an interface that allows users to rate songs. There are 6 options, ranging from 1 to 6. I want to change the css of the button upon clicking it.

There are several songs, and I display each one with `ng-repeat`.

```
ng-repeat="x in songs | unique: 'artistId'"
```

and these two directives make up the first option.

```
<score-six-s tracks='x'>6</score-six-s>
<score-six-n trackn='x'>Number</score-six-n>
```

When the user clicks an element that wraps the above two, the scope is updated with their preference. Here is the problem

```
myApp.directive('scoreSixN', function() {
function link (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(track.score, function(value) {
        updateButton(value);
    });
    function updateButton(value) {
        if (value === 6) {
            element.css({
                fontSize: '19px', 
                color: '#66caff'
            });
        } else {
            element.css({
                fontSize: '15px',
                color: '#99dbff'
            });
        }
    }
}
return {
    scope : {
        track: '=trackn'
    },
    link: link
}
});
```

I'm getting an error: `ReferenceError: track is not defined` in the console log and the line of the error is `scope.$watch(track.score.....`

In the isolate scope, I specified that `track` is supposed to be whatever value `trackn` binds to right? The `score` property of `x` specifies what rating the user gave the song. The element's text's color is supposed to change and it's size is supposed to increase when the user clicks on it basically.

Comment: you need to use `scope.$watch($scope.track.score` or `scope.$watch('track.score'`

Comment: wouldn't need this directive if you used `ng-class` and change the class when value of score is six

Comment: @charlietfl yea....its kind of stupid what I'm doing, new to angularjs, I didn't know about that directive, thanks